# Usage of the words ONE OF THE

Tags: word-usage

Is it grammatically correct to use the words **one of the**, in the following sentence.

> "**One of the**, if not the worst in its category"

Or should the sentence be:

> "**one of the worst**, if not the worst in its category.

Answer (score 1):

The first form is grammatically correct. The second is, I think, much more common, and is usually better and clearer writing.